# How to open Play! 2.0 console in Intellij IDEA?

Tags: java, scala, playframework, intellij-idea, playframework-2.0

Please note(!): *I'm installed all required plugins (see rest of my question), so this question is not duplicate!*
Original question: I setup new Play 2.0 Framework project using Intellj IDEA. But I can't find how to run `Play!`'s command-line utility in Intellij IDEA. From tutorials I learn it must be accessible from `Tools | Play with Playframework`.

But I missed this context menu:
[image]

Where can be problem?

Some additional info:

- I setup new project using Intellij IDEA wizard.
- I able to run application from Intellij IDEA using `Run` command and see result in browser.
- I use Intellij Idea 12.1.1
- To be able to create new project from IDEA I installed all additional plugins (Play 2.0 plugin, Scala plugin)

Answer (score 0):

You need to enable Play! support for particular module. Right-click on the module root, choose "Add framework support..." and choose Play!2.

Comment: Is that available on the community edition?

Comment: No, as far as I know.